# Created storyboard animation but not worikng with rows and colums wpf xaml c#

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

[image]

When checkBox selection is done two buttons will animated i just want to do like that,that grid comes in full view i tried rowspan and columspan but not working don't know how to work with it. comes in full view my animation with connection other side of window.

code =>

```
<Window x:Class="Login.View.ControlPanel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ControlPanel" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Checked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <!--<Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                        To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                    </Storyboard>-->
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid">
                            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0">
                                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingThicknessKeyFrame>
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Unchecked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <!--<Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                        To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                    </Storyboard>-->
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid">
                            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0 0 0 -66">
                                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingThicknessKeyFrame>
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="SilverLight" Margin="10"/>
        <TextBlock Text=".Net Framework" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text=" Printer Drivers" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Email Listner" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Scanner Component" Margin="10" Grid.Row="4"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Scanner Driver Version 1.0.0" Margin="10" Grid.Row="5"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbSilverlight" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="10"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbNetframework" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="10"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbAlisprinter" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="10"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbEmaillistner" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  Margin="10"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbScanner" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"  Margin="10"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbScannerDriver" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"  Margin="10"/>

        <Grid Grid.Row="7" Name="ControlsGrid" Height="66"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Black" Margin="0 0 0 -66">
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Height="30" Width="70" Margin="10" Foreground="White" Background="Green">Cancel</Button>
                <Button Height="30" Width="70" Margin="10" Foreground="White" Background="Green">Proceed</Button>
            </WrapPanel>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What exactly problem is? you mean grid (with black background) should not appear and only button should be animated from bottom? What do you mean by "comes in full view my animation with connection other side of window.". What is "connection" here?

Comment: @Coder sorry connection means stick that grid to other side means animation comes in full side, want animation in full row  but that comes only in 1st columns what should i do

Comment: What I understood is that you don't want grid to appear at all. When checkbox is checked, you only want to animate  'Cancel' & 'Proceed' button together from bottom of the screen. Please let me know if my understanding is correct?

Comment: @Coder go through this link u will understand               http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/5638b36d-5378-4552-aa44-6d6130d3709b_telerik-control-panel---justmock-vs-support-selected.png?sfvrsn=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** I have modified your code to fix the issue.

**Modified Code:**

```
<Window x:Class="Login.View.ControlPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ControlPanel" Height="400" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Checked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <!--<Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                        To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                    </Storyboard>-->
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid">
                                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0">
                                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                    </EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                </EasingThicknessKeyFrame>
                            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Unchecked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <!--<Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                        To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                    </Storyboard>-->
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid">
                                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0 0 0 -66">
                                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                    </EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                </EasingThicknessKeyFrame>
                            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> 
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="SilverLight" Margin="10"/>
            <TextBlock Text=".Net Framework" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="ALIS Printer Drivers" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="ALIS Email Listner" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <TextBlock Text="ALIS Scanner Component" Margin="10" Grid.Row="4"/>
            <TextBlock Text="ALIS Scanner Driver Version 1.0.0" Margin="10" Grid.Row="5"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbSilverlight" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="10"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbNetframework" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="10"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbAlisprinter" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="10"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbEmaillistner" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  Margin="10"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbScanner" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"  Margin="10"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbScannerDriver" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"  Margin="10"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DockPanel Name="ControlsGrid" Height="66" Background="Black"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,-66">
                <Button  DockPanel.Dock= "Right" Height="30" Width="70" Margin="10,5" Foreground="White" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Cancel</Button>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Height="30" Width="70" Margin="10,5" Foreground="White" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Proceed</Button>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```